# What frequency of sound waves produces the most vibration

Tags: acoustics, frequency, resonance, vibrations

The name of the question is rather contradictory and counter-intuitive since sound is *produced* by vibration. However, very low frequencies around 32Hz and receding are bass.

From what I have read online, you can feel frequencies below 20Hz which is what we normally hear, yet you can hear as low as 12Hz while amplifying very high frequencies (above 20k Hz? I'm not an expert). So again, which frequency(ies) should I amplify in my equalizer to achieve this effect?

Comment: Can I assume the lower the frequency, the more of an effect? I guess I just answered my own question... Logically, high frequencies you don't feel because they are so fast. (Don't quote me on this next part as I'm most likely wrong) I do believe we can feel all frequencies, its just the amount of time we hear/ feel them, but if that were true, then all frequencies would feel the same, so that leads me to conclude this is an effect of what we have defined as time to be the reason(which makes sense).

Comment: The frequency that produces the most vibration will resonate the material. If you take a bowl of water, a tome in the middle frequencies will produce waves in the water. At the right frequency, these waves will create a standing wave with noticeable peaks. At half the frequency, you get 1/2 the peaks. Eventually, at one frequency, you won't get a standing wave; this frequency is (probably) 1/2 the resonant frequency. Of course, every object has it's own resonant frequency. I hope this helps.

Comment: Maximum vibration happens when you cause an object to resonate.  You need to match the length of the object to the speed of sound in that object.  The details can be quite complex for complex shapes.

Comment: how about some specifications that may help answer (Turtle Beach EarForce X12): 50mm diameter speakers. fc response 20-20kHz. Bass Boost: Variable up to +12dB@150Hz(so that there should signal perhaps the maximum vibration freq.?) and an acoustic breathable mesh (for comfort, and apparently, noise reduction. Because why else put that many holes on it?)

Comment: @Brandon Enright I cannot change my headphones to match the length required. Expecially with the amount of polygons on headphones, talk about lots of calculus with lots of variations depending on the part of the headphones. I would assume Bass Boosting headphones cause the headset itself to resonate. Im quite close apparently because my EQ setting has caused a great deal of vibration.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer headphones are probably physically too small to produce the frequencies you want at a reasonable amplitude.

Comment: Again the specification says 50mm diameter speakers, which are pretty big. And it does indeed give quite the boost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean: for a given loudness, which frequencies involve greater physical movement, high frequencies or low? And that is simple - the lower the frequency the greater the amplitude of the movement. Here's a simple demonstration. Take the grille cloth off a speaker with a woofer. Play music through the speaker, something with sustained notes like organ music. Watch the surface of the woofer. For very low notes you can *see* the speaker move. It's true that the woofer only handles the very low notes, but if you use a speaker with, for instance, a woofer and a tweeter only, the woofer handles quite a range of frequencies, although not as great as a system with more speakers.

In general, all else being equal, a vibrating surface which has a fixed excursion (length of motion) will produce sound pressure levels (basically, loudness, although the perception of loudness gets complicated, and varies somewhat with frequency) which are proportional to the square of the frequency. That is, if you double the frequency you quadruple the pressure levels.